# Resolving "$ref" in serde_json/serde_yaml

Tags: json, rust, serde, json-ref

What is the best way to recursively resolve all [JSON `$ref`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03) in JSON documents?

A direct approach is to create a `Deserialize` implementation that accepts either a `{"$ref"}` object or a desired value, say an enum like this:

```
enum JRef<T> {
    Value(T),
    Ref(URI),
}

impl<'de, T> Deserialize<'de> for JRef<T> { ... }
```

But this would require me to wrap all my types in `JRef<T>`, so my `derive(Deserialize)` schema struct is filled with the boilerplate:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    a: JRef<Bar>,
    b: JRef<(JRef<Qux>, JRef<Corge>)>,
    ...
}
```

In addition, the resolution of the reference is also boilerplate.

I understand that the direct deserialization of a type should not depend on some external state, so it makes sense to first deserialize into a `JRef` and then resolve them later. But to prevent writing boilerplate code, the resolution performed later could be performed using a custom proc-macro that derives a JRef-free-type of the original type, which implement a trait that accepts a foreign function and resolves URIs using the foreign function.

So far, I have dug deep into the dependency ecosystem in order to just resolve a single `$ref`. Do I really need to do all these, or is there a simpler solution I have missed?

Comment: That is a *really* loaded question. I also do not think it is a good place to do that on the `Deserialize` step - it is probably better to do the fetching one step before, since by that point you'll have JSON objects (of whatever library you use) instead of a single `{ "$ref": "... }` key, which makes `Deserialize` work out of the box.

Comment: You don't really know what references you want to load before the deserialization. In some schemas, not every single `{"$ref"}` would need to be resolved. Parsing with serde_json might be necessary to locate the exact references that need to be resolved.

Comment: so, it has been 3 years, what did you do?

Comment: @user3054986 I used a postprocessing step after the serde parsing. It seems that serde doesn't really like stateful conversion. On an unrelated note, I also developed [xylem](https://github.com/SOF3/xylem), a stateful conversion framework, which is designed to serve as a post-serde processing stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think: It depends. What is the further purpose of your code?

- Do you just need deserialization for code generation?
- Are you modifying the JSON and serialize it again?

For the first case, there is a good example: [schemafy](https://github.com/Marwes/schemafy)
A) In [schemafy_lib/src/schema.rs](https://github.com/Marwes/schemafy/blob/master/schemafy_lib/src/schema.rs) the schema to be serialized can be found. It contains a $ref, of type Option.
B) Further, [schemafy_lib/src/lib.rs](https://github.com/Marwes/schemafy/blob/master/schemafy_lib/src/lib.rs) contains an Expander, transforming the $ref into Rust source code. (At least that is my understanding.)

I have to deal with the latter case - serializing as well as deserializing.
From the first example a take A and skip B. I plan to put my Schema into an object, hiding the $ref while clients may deals with JSON objects transparently.

Comments are welcome.